# Google play store Alpha & Beta distribution issues

Tags: android, google-play, alpha, google-play-console, beta

I have an app that previously had a beta release that was promoted to production. The version code of this app was 1.3.x (y)

We updated the app and updated the version and we created an alpha release with the new apk. The version code of this app is 1.4.x (y+1). We have given ourselves invites for the alpha track.

Although the documentation and the forums say that if an account is eligible for both beta & alpha he will receive the alpha version, I can see this doesn't work in my case.

The link for opt-in is the same for both alpha & beta, and when I enter with an account eligible for both, it takes me to the 1.3.x(y) beta app, instead of the one from alpha.

About 4 hours passed and alpha usually is distributed instantly, so I don't know what the problem might be.

As far as I can see, the link sends to the beta app, not the alpha one. If I add a person only to the alpha program and go to the app on that account or to the link `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.package.name` it says I am not allowed.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution? I'm facing similar issues.

Comment: I did not unfortunately

Comment: Same problem for me ... I'm in Alpha and Beta diffusion list, I removed myself from beta to force use the alpha, waited 24h, no change ... I'm already take the beta version, and I'm not in the beta anymore x)